# Inserting a MYSQL variable containing CSVs into table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable that contains CSVs that I would like to insert into a table in an efficient way since this is an operation that will be performed many times a day.

```
CSV_To_Be_Inserted = "Y101, E103, I710, U809"  (this list will be closer to 100 values each time)
```

I only want to insert the values that aren't already in the table.  I've tried this in PHP using a loop that calls an insert statement for each one and it took about 17 seconds.

I've also tried passing the whole CSV variable into MYSQL and looping through the values in MYSQL and it took 15 seconds.

Any ideas on how to get this under 4 or 5 seconds?

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You must using group insert for increase performance of mysql query !

```
<?php

    $CSV_To_Be_Inserted = '....';

    $csv = explode("\n",$CSV_To_Be_Inserted); //Split every Line
    $values = [];
    foreach($csv as $record){
        $rec = "'".str_replace(", ","', '",$record)."'"; //add ' on columns
        $values[]=' ('.$rec.' )';
    }
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ".implode(',',$values).";");
```

Comment: This Code has been Edited!

Comment: Thanks, I will test this tonight and report back